# Data is saved, but when I load my variables they come up as 0 and program catches my Load exception

Tags: java, oop, exception, text-files

Hello I am trying to make a textfile using outfile and infile. Its seems that my saveData method is working correctly. However, my loadData method does not print out the correct data for my RentalDays and RentalRate. When I run the program it catches the exception I made for load and creates a text file called sample.txt. The text inside my sample.txt file prints RentalDays 0 and RentalRate 0. Please Help. Ask questions if I am not clear enough.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class TractorText {
       private static int RentalRate;
       private static int RentalDays;

       public int setRentalRate(int RentalRate) {
            if (RentalRate <= 0 || RentalRate > 100000) 
            {
              return -1;
            } 
            else 
            {
               return RentalRate;

            }
         }


       public int setRentalDays(int RentalDay) {
            if (RentalDays <= 0 || RentalDays > 365) 
            {
              return -1;
            } 
            else 
            {

               return RentalDays;
            }
         }

          TractorText() {
      setRentalRate(20);
      setRentalDays(30);
   }

TractorText(int RentalRate, int RentalDays) {
          this.RentalRate = setRentalRate(RentalRate);
          this.RentalDays = setRentalDays(RentalDays);
       }
          public static void saveData(String filename) throws Exception {
                File outFile = new File(filename);
                FileOutputStream outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(outFileStream);

                //write values of primitive data types to the stream
                outStream.println("Rental Days " + RentalDays);
                outStream.println("Rental Rate" + RentalRate);

                outStream.close();

            }

            public static void loadData(String filename) throws Exception {

                File inFile = new File(filename);
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inFile);
                BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                String turn;
                turn = bufReader.readLine();
                int g = Integer.parseInt(turn);
                System.out.println(g);
                turn = bufReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(turn);

                bufReader.close();

               }

       public static void main(String[] args){
           try { saveData("sample.txt"); }
            catch ( Exception e) { System.out.println("Error saving data."); }


            try { loadData("sample.txt"); }
            catch ( Exception e) { System.out.println("Loading data..."); }


       }

    }
```

Comment: The input strings you are parsing are not integers.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
try { loadData("sample.txt"); }
        catch ( Exception e) { System.out.println("Loading data..."); }
```

to

```
try { loadData("sample.txt"); }
        catch ( Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Loading data..."); }
```

and got

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Rental Days 0"
Loading data...
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at tractortext.TractorText.loadData(TractorText.java:70)
    at tractortext.TractorText.main(TractorText.java:84)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`